# How can I make my UpdatePanel scroll?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I can't put a DIV inside it (says it's not allowed) and a DIV around it causes an IE error. Reverting to compatibility mode doesn't work.

I populate the UpdatePanel dynamically, depending on some other factors and sometimes it can be several pages in length, so I need it to be scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem having a div either inside or outside an update panel.

I can only conclude you've got an error in your markup.

Comment: Doh I just remembered it has to go into the content template!